# How can I declare singleton object from added webService to abp Project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

We start with this kind of abpTemplates:

- EntityFramewrok
- AngularJs
- SPA

We have refrenced webService from another project in this one.
Is it true that initiate one instance from WebService object in entire of project. if it is true. how?

Comment: Why negative point?

Comment: nobody understands your question.show us some code and show what you did up to now.

Comment: Agreed, I have no idea what you're asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create only 1 instance from your webservice proxy class then you have to add **ISingletonDependency** to your webservice proxy class and you have to create this servis via dependency injection.  This way you can be sure that it'll be created only once.

```
public interface IPersonManager
{
    //...
}

public class MyPersonManager : IPersonManager, ISingletonDependency
{
    //...
}
```